# Convert simple SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

This sql query is quite simple. It retrieves the id of all concerts where all of the booked artist are sick (excluding some of the concerts of a specific type).

I have tried to convert this to a LINQ expression but I am totally stuck. Would appreciate if someone could help me out.

(The table `ArtistConcert` simply connects `Concert` with `Artist`)

```
select ac.concertID
from 
    ArtistConcert ac
    join Concert c on c.ConcertID = ac.ConcertID
    join Artist a on a.artistID = ac.artistID
where 
    a.IsSick = 1 and c.TypeID not in (1,2,3)
    and
    c.StartTime > getdate() 
    and not
    exists
    (
        select _a.artistID from ArtistConcert _ac
        join Concert _c on _c.ConcertID = _ac.ConcertID
        join Artist _a on _a.artistID = _ac.artistID        
        where _c.concertID = c.concertID and _a.IsSick = 0 
    )
```

Comment: A lambda expression that would only be embarrassing to post

Comment: An attempt to solve the problem you are facing is seen very positively by the SO community. Even if it is clumsy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your datacontext is `ctx`

```
var typeIds = new[] {1,2,3};

var query = from ac in ctx.ArtistConcert
            join c in ctx.Concert on ac.ConcertID equals c.ConcertId
            join a in ctx.Artist on ac.artistID equals a.artistID
            where a.IsSick == 1 && !typeIds.Contains(c.TypeId)
            && c.StartTime > DateTime.Now
            && !ctx.ArtistConcert.Any(_ac => _ac.ConcertID == c.ConcertId 
                                             && ctx.Artist.Any(_a => _a.artistID == _ac.artistId 
                                                                     && _a.isSick == 0))
            select ac.ConcertId;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck on the sql "exists" part. :)

Comment: How do I mark an answer as "answer" so everyone can see that the question is solved? (sorry, my first day at this site)